# Django model Slug field unique_for_month not working

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django v. 1.11.3. Here is my model field declaraion.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, unique_for_month='pub_date')
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_post_detail', kwargs={'year': self.pub_date.year,
                                                'month':  self.pub_date.month,
                                                'slug': self.slug,})
```

I use ModelForms to create the user forms as follows.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_slug(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
```

However, when I try to enter duplicated slug and redirect to the newly created post it is created in the db and get method call fails due to multiple object return.

Here is the URL config and FBV for the detail page.

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 
post_detail, name='blog_post_detail'),

def post_detail(request, year, month, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pub_date__year=year, pub_date__month=month, 
    slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Finally, this is the error shown in debug data.

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /blog/2018/8/python-3-programming/
get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!

~/workspace/src/blog/views.py in post_detail
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pub_date__year=year, pub_date__month=month, 
    slug=slug)
```

I checked with the db and I see two entries for the same slug in the same month. What is wrong here?

Update CBV code:

```
class PostCreate(View):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form_class()})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': bound_form})
```

Comment: Please show us the view that handles the `PostForm` used to create new posts?

Comment: Refer updated code.

Comment: Maybe you saved a record and _then_ changed the model with the unique constraint?